# Understanding a JsonMappingException with Google Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I am trying to understand why I get the error with some GET calls and not others with a Google App Engine Entity.

The class

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Assessment> assessment;

    public List<Assessment> getAssessment() {
        return assessment;
    }

    public void setAssessment(List<Assessment> assessment) {
        this.assessment = assessment;
    }
}
```

**Works**

And if I use a `list` request, It works fine.

```
GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/clientendpoint/v1/client
```

The result is as expected

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "Client",
    "appId": "no_app_id",
    "id": "12",
    "complete": true
   },
   "firstName": "Jane",
   "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
   "id": {
    "kind": "Client",
    "appId": "no_app_id",
    "id": "13",
    "complete": true
   },
   "firstName": "Jon",
   "lastName": "Doe",
  }
 ]
}
```

**Doesn't work**

But if I get just 1 record, such as select id 12, an error is produced

```
GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/clientendpoint/v1/client/12
```

> com.google.appengine.repackaged.org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException:
>   You have just attempted to access field \"assessment\" yet this field
>   was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this
>   field, or detach it when detaching the object. (through reference
>   chain:
>   com.google.api.server.spi.response.CollectionResponse[\"items\"]->com.google.appengine.datanucleus.query.StreamingQueryResult[0]->com.my.app.client.Client[\"assessment\"])

**Works if I remove the get / set methods**

Where I'm confused is if I comment out the `setAssessment(...)` and `getAssesment()` methods inside the `Client` object, it works fine.

```
@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @ElementCollection
    private List<Assessment> assessment;

    //public List<Assessment> getAssessment() {
    //    return assessment;
    //}

    //public void setAssessment(List<Assessment> assessment) {
    //    this.assessment = assessment;
    //}
}
```

It works fine

```
GET http://localhost:8888/_ah/api/clientendpoint/v1/client/12
```

Result

```
{
 "id": {
  "kind": "Client",
  "appId": "no_app_id",
  "id": "12",
  "complete": true
 },
 "firstName": "Jane",
 "lastName": "Doe"
}
```

**My questions are**

- Why does it work when I comment out the get/set
- How do I properly fix this?
- I'm having trouble finding good examples of code for Java App Engine code, other than the simple examples in the docs. Anyone know of any good examples?

**Relevant Endpoint code**

```
/**
 *
 * This method works fine
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listClient")
public CollectionResponse<Client> listClient(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    EntityManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<Client> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getEntityManager();
        Query query = mgr.createQuery("select from Client as Client");
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            query.setHint(JPACursorHelper.CURSOR_HINT, cursor);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setFirstResult(0);
            query.setMaxResults(limit);
        }

        execute = (List<Client>) query.getResultList();
        cursor = JPACursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Client> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}

/**
 *
 * This method errors out
 *
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getClient")
public Client getClient(@Named("id") Long id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Client client = null;
    client = mgr.find(Client.class, id);
    mgr.close();
    return client;
}
```

Comment: On the surface this looks like a problem with lazy loading again, but I'm not sure. Do you have `assessment` set to a non-null value in any of your entities? It's not showing a value in your example `list` call, I just want to make sure that's accurate.

Comment: I haven't yet entered anything into `assessment` yet. Not all entities will have them. Do I need to just initialize `assessment` inside of the constructor?

Comment: No, I was just checking that lack of `assessment`s in your `list` call wasn't an error. I'll have to play around with this a bit to figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, and it's definitely a lazy-loading issue:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getClient")
public Client getClient(@Named("id") Long id) {
    EntityManager mgr = getEntityManager();
    Client client = mgr.find(Client.class, id);
    if (client != null)
        client.getAssessment();  // Forces it to load your objects
    mgr.close();
    return client;
}
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a cleaner way to fix this, so please let me know if you have better alternatives!
One final thing: I also would love to know why it behaves differently when Kirk comments out the getters/setters.

**EDIT 26/12/2013:**
It seems like fetch types are now properly working using the latest version of App Engine + Datanucleus. I also found a very interesting behaviour:

- If you use `TypedQuery<T>` instead of `Query`, JPA will try to load all of T's fields (it ignores `FetchType.LAZY`), and you will get a JsonMappingException if those fields weren't manually loaded.
- If you use `Query`, JPA will only load the fields marked as `FetchType.EAGER`, so watch out for exceptions if you intend to use fields that were marked as lazy but weren't properly loaded.

Comment: Also, the FetchType.EAGER seems to be ignored, according to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-java/Mk3-yaqnJxQ

Comment: Yeah, good call. It looks like my advice to use `EAGER` was invalid. For the `list` method, there are a few lines missing from the snippet above `for (Lazy obj : execute)` performs the eager loading in the list method. You'll need to do a sub-loop `for (Assessment assessment : obj.getAssessment())` to eagerly load that property.

Comment: I'll take a look at this later on today once I am with the code. Thank you for the help

Comment: Worked just fine, and thank you for following up with my last question @DanHolevoet. That worked. Not sure why commenting out those two methods fixed it before though.